# How to validate a model in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/) and I have created a model, and most of its attributes are required, but if I post a JSON with most of its attributes missing it will still create the record in the db. I'm using [`sails-postgresql`](https://github.com/particlebanana/sails-postgresql).
I've even tried doing it manually with:

```
ModelName.create(req.body).done(function(){})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a special fields to your models attributes - "required: true" or "minLength: 5"

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      maxLength: 20,
      minLength: 5
    },

    email: {
      type: 'email',
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

You can read about validation in sails models here - http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models